# Netbeans Removing JPanel does not remove from source

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7

I made a `JTabbedPane` using Netbeans 7.4. After adding a few things, I decided I didn't want all of the tabs I have created anymore. I then simply compied the `JPanel` inside of the `JTabbedPane` onto the same `JFrame`, and deleted the now unused `JTabbedPane`. Thing is, all the variables used are still being initialised in source code, even though they do not show up in the `Design Navigator` or on the `JFrame` in design mode.

I know I can simply edit this out with a external editor, but I am afraid that the Form data will be corrupted. (This has happened to me before and I lost the ability to edit using `Design Mode`.)

I used the inspector and FindBugs, but I failed to remove it from there.

"Why am I using Netbeans!?" - A question I won't be asking myself again after I sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Your first real problem is you are using the Design Mode. Netbeans isn't the problem as is is more than capable of working by itself with code only (I will always only use code).

It is really easy to break a program with a incorrect move within design view.

There isn't really an easy way to go about fixing it, although IMHO sift through the code and find what you need to remove. **Make a copy of the .java file first so you have a backup if it breaks!**